# Creating simple table in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm just trying to create simple javascript function that outputs a small table but can't seem to get it working.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset ="utf-8">
    <title>Test Table</title>
    <script type = text/javascript>

        function drawTable()
        {
            var tableDiv = document.getElementById( "numbersTable" );

            tableDiv.innerHTML = "<table>" + 
            "<caption>Numbers Table</caption>" +
            "<thead><th>Number</th><th>Square</th><th>Cube</th></thead>" +
            "<tbody><tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>" +
            "</tbody></table>";
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id = "numbersTable"></div>
</body>
```

Can anyone see where the problem is?

Comment: Where are you calling `drawTable()` from?

Comment: Also remove the spaces between id = "numbersTable" - it's not a valid XML/HTML

Comment: I'm not sure but js don't like new lines for string merging. You should use string+="<table>"; instead. Also you should call drawTable() somewhere

Comment: @Anthony it does not change anything (it only takes more memory because every part is stored as an separate object, but it won't affect the user that much)

Comment: A [`<thead>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/HTML_Elements/thead) element has _permitted content_ of `Zero or more <tr> elements`. You should wrap your `<th>` tags together in a `<tr>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. you don't call `drawTable()`
2. remember to call it after `<div id="numbersTable"></div>`

Comment: That's what I'm confused about.  Where should I call the function drawTable?

Comment: 1. window.onload = drawTable; 2. <script>drawTable();</script> just before the </body> tag - these are simplest options, choose which you want (I suggest the second)

Comment: I got another quick question, if I was to style the table with external CSS sheet would I add elements inside the function or does it need to go in the body?

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean, you just put CSS rules into stylesheet and they will be appened right after call drawTable()

Comment: I have external CSS style sheet that that I link to.  If I wanted to apply the styling from external CSS sheet to my table would I just do it inside my function where I started the table?  Like tableDiv.innerHTML = "<table class="styledtable">"